# insights/shared return 403 while insights/used return successful response

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I use Graph Explorer to test it.

API: GET /users/{userPrincipalName}/insights/shared, return 403.

API: GET /users/{userPrincipalName}/insights/used, return 200 and used documents.

Both API required same permission:
Sites.Read.All, Sites.ReadWrite.All

Anyone can help on it?

[image: access token Snapshot]

Comment: Use https://jwt.ms/ to parse your access token and provide screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/insights/shared`, please make sure you have the **Sites.Read.All** or **Sites.ReadWrite.All** `application permissions` (don't forget to grant **admin consent** for this permission), because no users are logged in at the `/users` endpoint. Then you need to use the [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) to get the access token.

[image]

[image]

---

**Update：**

When you use **Graph Explorer** to test, because you need to log in as a user, you actually use the token obtained by the **userName/Password flow**. according to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/insights-list-shared?view=graph-rest-1.0#http-request): **Only the user can make requests using the user's id or principal name.**

[image]

When you log in to a user, you can only use the id or principal name of the logged in user. You cannot use the id of other users, otherwise, a 403 error will be reported. But when you use other tools such as postman for testing, because you do not log in as a user, but use the application as the service principal to make a request, so, you can get a list of shared documents from other users.

Summarized in one sentence:  As long as you are logged in as a user, you can only get the list of shared documents of the logged-in user. If you want to get the list of shared documents from other users, , don't log in users.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.).This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: /insights/shared and /insights/used have same permission, /insights/used works but /insights/shared not. So it's not permission issue here. I use Graph Exploreer to test it.

Comment: @KingCao  You need to grant application permissions to the application, and then use postman for testing. I just used Graph Explorer to test and it also returned 403 to me because Graph Explorer uses delegated permissions by default.

Comment: the interesting thing is I can get insights/used via Graph Explorer, insights/used has same permission as insights/shared according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/officegraphinsights?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: @KingCao  I updated the answer to give you a detailed explanation.